# How to change URL in Angular 2 by click?

Tags: angular

I have nested component `language` inserted in `appComponent` with HTML link:

```
<li [routerLink]="['/language', lang.code]">Choose</a>
```

And routing:

```
{ path: 'language/:id', component: LanguageComponent }
```

Problem is that when I click on the link it loads component `language` in main page. But I need just reload `language` inside `appComponent`. Or others words, only change URL address.

Comment: did you add router outlet in appComponent HTML ?

Comment: Yes, exactly, but may be it I need two outlets, because main is reload main page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add `replaceUrl` to your `<li>` element which will overwrite the previously URL.

This is will still load the component language but it won't dump unnecessary navigation history into your user's browser.

Comment: Can you share example, I dont understand what you mean